# Symfony error Unable to find template

Tags: php, symfony, payum

After setting up paypal express checkout I am now setting up the stripe payment gateway as per the instructions provided [here](http://payum.org/doc/0.14/PayumBundle/custom_purchase_examples/stripe_checkout) but yet I am getting an error of

`Unable to find template "@PayumStripe/Action/obtain_checkout_token.html.twig" : "Bundle "PayumStripe" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?"`

As per the instructions I have added the following in `AppKernel` what else do I need to add?

`new Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\PayumBundle(),`

Comment: have you missed updating the routing?

Comment: i dont see anything related to routing in documentation. if i am missing something please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the documentation that was under development, after looking at the [stable](http://payum.org/doc/0.13/PayumBundle/custom_purchase_examples/stripe_checkout) version of documtation i found out that i was missing the mapping of path in config.yml

According to the documentation the path is supposed to be

```
paths:
    %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/payum/src/Payum/Core/Resources/views: PayumCore
    %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/payum/src/Payum/Stripe/Resources/views: PayumStripe
```

However I feel that is incorrect as those directory do not exist and this is the error one sees, so those paths have to be corrected and the following worked for me

```
paths:
    %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/Resources/views: PayumCore
    %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/Bridge/Symfony/Resources/views: PayumSymfonyBridge
    %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/stripe/Payum/Stripe/Resources/views: PayumStripe
```

Comment: It is not a bug, you can install payum/payum in that case vendor will be as it is in the doc, but you installed just core + stirpe. It is a different packages  and the folders in vendor are different.

Current master has to add this paths automatically. There is no need to define them manually. Doesn't it worked for you?

Comment: it is working now after changing the paths i mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this to your routing.yml:

```
# app/config/routing.yml

payum_capture:
    resource: "@PayumBundle/Resources/config/routing/capture.xml"

payum_authorize:
    resource: "@PayumBundle/Resources/config/routing/authorize.xml"

payum_notify:
    resource: "@PayumBundle/Resources/config/routing/notify.xml"
```

taken from here: http://payum.org/doc/0.14/PayumBundle/get_it_started

Comment: thats already been added, as mentioned that paypal is already working. Stripe was the second payment gateway i was trying to add